# VBS CreateFolder not working

Tags: windows, vbscript

I am trying to write a simple VBS script that will create folders on my work machine.

Here is the code:

```
Dim newFolder
Dim fileSys
Dim objShell

newFolder = "C:\Program Files\MyNewApp"
set objShell = createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

if not objShell.FolderExists(newFolder) then
    set filesys=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
    filesys.CreateFolder(newFolder) 
end if
```

When I run the script (by double-clicking it on my Desktop), I get an error dialog stating that this file already exists.

I go to `C:\\Program Files\` and look for a directory called `MyNewApp` and see nothing.

Is anything glaringly-wrong with this simple script? I suspect this could be a permissions issue. Maybe all work machines get deployed without write/execute permissions for the Program Files directory. But that doesn't make a whole lot of sense either, because I've installed *lots* of software on this machine, and each application has nested a directory inside of Program Files.

Any ideas?

Comment: isn't that folder in place but hidden?

Comment: The days of programs arbitrarily hacking sensitive folders like c:\program files are over and done with.  You'll have to run the script interpreter from an elevated command prompt on Vista and up.  Also beware of 64-bit operating systems and c:\program files (x86).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is correct. You can put on top of the code:

```
    on error resume next
```

'then on the end if you want you can put the following to describe to you whats up.

```
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
       MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Description 
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a **file** named `MyNewApp` (non-extension) In `C:\Program Files\`, delete it.

Answer (score 0):

No it was a permission issue - I changed the create directory to `C:\\` and it works fine. I'm gonna leave it at that and close this ticket! Thanks for the answers though!

Comment: Because there is no file named MyNewApp in C:\. You get an error says "File already exists". No Folder, No Permission, just File.

Comment: There was no file in Program Files with the name MyNewApp either - so permission issue is the only possibility here ;-)